# Rounded rectangle with 3D effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, 3d

I'm trying to make a sort of rounded rectangle card with a slight 3D effect.

Below is a basically what I have now. I make 3 rounded rectangles, and skew the "shadow" layers towards the bottom right.

[image]

It looks okay, but I just designed by eye and have no idea how the angles on any of the skews should be. Does anyone have reference or technique how to get this pixel perfect?

Thanks

Comment: Just wondering: Did you choose to draw the shadows yourself? Why not use a blending option such as bevel and emboss?

Comment: I gave that a try, but couldn't make it look similar to my design.

Answer (score 3):

Start with your rounded rectangle:

[image]

Then draw three lines that converge in the same spot somewhere to the bottom right of the rectangle:

[image]

Now, using the pen tool, draw a shape like this (make sure the corners line up nicely).

[image]

Now add a gradient to the new shape, reduce the opacity and change the angle to match the angle of the middle perspective line. Here's the settings that worked for mine.

[image]

Create a new rounded rectangle below the shaded extruded layer but above the perspective lines:

[image]

Go to the layer panel and clip the extrusion layer to the new rectangle by holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and clicking between the layers, the layer panel should look like this:

[image]

And here's the final product:

[image]

Comment: You'll need to change the color of the white rectangle to match your background.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done under Adobe Illustrator (and then optionally placed in the Photoshop document). This effect is called oblique projection. Here is the final result:
[image]

I've created an Adobe® Illustrator® Plug-in called Oblique Projection 'opo' to automate the creation process of Parallel 3D Effect (Extrude Effect). It is quick and gives you full control over the appearance of the extrusion. 
Everything is on one layer so you can easily separate it from the rest of the artwork. Plus it is divided into logical parts - this way every letter (or even every part of the letter) can be modified fully independently.

[image]

Here is how I would create the effect you are asking for:

a) install ‘opo’ extension (free evaluation copy available here:
    http://63mutants.com/subc/products/opo_m01/opo_m01.php)

b) add extra point to the lower, right corner of the rectangle (using ‘Add Anchor Point Tool’):

[image]

c) select your rounded rectangle

d) go to ‘opo’ panel, type (for example) 20px for X and -20 Y direction. Select Projection Z-Order ‘Z-‘, and ‘Solid’ Projection Type. Choose ‘Custom Projection Color’, put 153, 153, 153 into fill; leave the stroke blank (0).Hit ‘create projection’:

[image]

e) Finally, select the right side projection objects, and modify its color:

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Why did you delete this answer? Looks great to me!

Comment: sorry for that. once I've posted my answer I received 'down vote'. I thought this is because my answer points to the plug-in I've made and people may think this is a spam or something like that. But if you say it is good, I am posting it back. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score -3):

Yes, You can use bevel and emboss option, it will give perfect 3d effect to object

1. Take a new document
2. Create a rounded rectangle tool on a new layer
3. Select that layer
4. Go to Layer menu in that, select layer style, in that select `Bevel
   and Emboss` option
5. Do settings as per your requirement to emboss the object.

Comment: Hi Monica, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! Could you please elaborate a bit more, preferably with some instructions as to *how* to use `Bevel & Emboss` to achieve the desired effect? We value extensive, motivated answers of lasting value. Thanks again and enjoy the site!

Comment: I think the big question here is 'what settings' fot the `Bevel & Emboss?'